# Media queries messes with website css

Tags: php, html, css, media-queries

On my website, I added media queries to make it responsive to smart phones/tablets and it works perfectly when I am testing it. All of a sudden when I come back the next day, all my CSS on the website is messed up and the only way to fix it is to remove the media queries on the website. I believe the problem is when i specify the width and height of the website. Here's the media query code

Media Query Code:

```
@media (min-height: 1366px) and (min-width: 1024px) {

    #img-div{

    width: 15%;
    height: 20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;

}

    #container{

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;


}

    #login-div{
    width: 39vw;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .input-box{
    width: 100%;
     height: 60px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  border:  none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
    border-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing:border-box;

}

    #welcome-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}
}

@media (min-height: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px){


    #container{

     width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;


}

     #login-div{
    width: 39vw;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
         position: relative;
         top: 20%;
}

     #welcome-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
         position: relative;
         top: 20%;
}

     #img-div{

    width: 15%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
         top: 20%;
}
}

@media (min-height: 812px) and (min-width: 375px){

     #img-div{

    width: 15%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
         top: 12%;
}

    #welcome-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
     position: relative;
     top: 12%;
}
    #login-div{

    width: 78vw;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 12%;
}

    #forgotPass{

    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
}

    #remember{

    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 12%;
    padding-top: 1%;
}

}

@media (min-height: 375px) and (min-width: 812px){

     #img-div{

    width: 6%;
    height: 10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
     top: 5%;
    background-color: ;
}

     #welcome-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
     position: relative;
     top: 1%;
}

    #login-div{

    width: 39vw;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
}
    .bottom-text{

    float: left;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5%;
}

}
```

I use min-height/width because when you flip the screen horizontally, some queries have the same width so i have to specify. So my problem is that when I edit the media queries for the phones/tablets it works now and later when i come back, the website itself(not on the phones) looks all messed up. If someone can show me the best way to make your website responsive on the phones would be great. Here is my website code

Html and some php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){

    $error = "";
    $fullname = addslashes(trim($_POST['fullname-text']));
    $email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email-text']));
    $password = addslashes(trim($_POST['password-text']));
    $storePassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 10));

    if(!empty($fullname) && !empty($email) && !empty($password)){

        //Check if email is valid
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false){

            $error .= "Email not VALID";
        }

        //Check if passwrod is greater 6
        if(strlen($password) < 6){

            die ("Password has to be GREATER than 6 characters!");

        }


    }
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rotary Speaker Login Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rotarycss.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>

    <body>

      <div id="tint">

          <div id="container">

              <div id="img-div">
              <img src="yellow.png" id="logo">
              </div>

              <p id="welcome-text">Welcome to the Guest Speaker Forum</p>

              <div id="login-div">


              <form action="signup.php" method="post">

                    <input type="text" name="fullname-text" placeholder="Fullname" class="input-box" class="test">

                  <br><br/>
                    <input type="text" name="email-text" placeholder="Email" class="input-box">

                  <br><br/>
                <input type="password" name="password-text" placeholder="Password" class="input-box">

                  <br><br/>


            <button class="submit" name="submit">SIGN UP</button>  
          <br><br/>

        <a href="login.php" class="href-links"><p class="bottom-text">Already have an account?</p></a>

        <br><br/>

        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="href-links"><p id="goBack" class="bottom-text">&larr; Back to Website</p></a>


          </form>




              </div>



          </div>



        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    background-image: url(speaker.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
html, body {
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.8);
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#tint{

z-index: 1;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);   

}

#container{

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;
   background-color: ;

}


#img-div{

    width: 8%;
    height: 15%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 12%;
}

#logo{

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

#welcome-text{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    position: relative;
    top: 12%;
}

#login-div{

    width: 29vw;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 12%;
    background-color: ;
}


.input-box{
    width: 100%;
     height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  border:  none;
  padding: 5px 20px;
    border-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
    color:white;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
color: white !important;

}

.checkBox{

    width: 25px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;

}

.checkBox label{

    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;

}

.checkBox label:after{

    opacity: 0.2;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 6px;
    left: 7px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checkBox label:hover:after{

    opacity: 0.5;
}

.checkBox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after{

    opacity: 1;
}

#remember{

    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 7%;
    padding-top: 1%;
}

.submit{

    background-color: orange;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 27px;
  width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.8);
    font-size: 20px;
}

.bottom-text{

    float: left;

}

.bottom-text:hover{

    text-decoration: underline;
}
#forgotPass{

    position: relative;
    left: 55%;
}

#goBack{

    clear: both;
}

.href-links{

    color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.8);
}
```

How it looks when media query is added

Comment: Uploading screenshots of what you want and what you have might help.

Comment: General advice: You're trying to be too specific with your media queries. Remove `min-height` from your media queries and just use `min-width`.

Comment: I use min height cause when you flip it horizontally some queries have the same width

Comment: I added it @Jayson_X

Comment: Listen to @Jeffwa instead of saying why you are doing it. You're odd layout results are from your attempts to define parameters very tightly. You're making incorrect assumptions about browser window and device sizes. A very good solution is to only use width, and make sure the styles allow everything to fit nicely based on width. Then it always looks good on any device.

Comment: Oh true ill do that then. Thank you for the help.

Comment: use one min and max (as opposed to two minimums) in your media queries.. that's an important start!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your media querys are way too specific, you need to settle for 3, maybe 4, and make them all work properly. I would only use max-height on the mobile portrait mode, other than that there is no need and it will only cause you issues on different screens. Having 3 basic sizes (sm, md, lg) that look they way you want is better than having 7 faulty ones.

You have to re-check your @media sizes, they seem a bit odd: your heights are all larger than your widths, that would only be needed for mobile or tablet.

Also, using so many percentages for things such as the object placement (top, bottom, etc) will cause you problems with different devices constantly, it is easier to establish it in px and work from there. For the widths it is OK to use %, but be careful not to mix them with vw because, again, will cause trouble.

If you share it on fiddle would be ideal.

Comment: Oh i like your points! So i only use % when its for width and height? and for like positioning its best to use pixels?

Comment: Yes, precisely, I've found it easier to do it this way. Or even try to keep % for width only so it's easier to keep it responsive.